# Running a moveit task that runs a bash script which utilizes the Azure AzCopy utility

Tags: bash, azure, azure-blob-storage, azcopy, moveit

I have tried running a bash script, batch file and a script file,which utilizes the azcopy utility. The azcopy command copies files from a remote location to an azure blob storage.

AZCOPY /Source:$Source /Dest:$Destination /DestKey:$DestKey /Pattern:*.txt

It runs okay when i manually run the script. When i create a moveit task and run it, I receive a task completed successful.However, no files have been copied to the blob storage. I have tried
running the powershell command as well, C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.EXE -NoLogo -NoProfile –ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command c:\temp\GL_Format_Update.ps1. As mentioned in a stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41941311/how-to-execute-powershell-script-in-moveit-central).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're infrastructure looks like, but i'd recommend using Azure File Sync. You won't have to use AZCopy nor MoveIT. You should read about it here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-public-preview-for-azure-file-sync/

Azure files would also be a good alternative by attaching a file share, allowing to save files from local access to the cloud.

Comment: This Azure File Sync seems more of a solution for an intranet, as you are required to have an authorization header, when trying to maintain azure's blob storage.   What I am looking for is a solution whereby it is free of this authorization layer, for public use.